# Using Extension Methods from within an Object's constructor where "Me" is the ByRef target object

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods

Consider the following:

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub Initialize(ByRef Target as SomeClass, ByVal SomeParam as Something )
        ...
        Target  = SomethingElse
    end Sub
End Module

Class SomeClass
...

    sub New(ByVal SomeParam as Something )
       Me.Initialize(SomeParam)
    end sub

    sub New()

    end sub

End Class


'Case 1: Doesnt Work...why????:

    Dim foo as new SomeClass(SomeParam) 'foo remains uninitialized


'Case 2: Does Work:
    Dim foo as new SomeClass()
    foo.Initialize(SomeParam) 'foo is initialized
```

**Question:
Why is Case 1 failing to initialize the object as expected?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that VB.Net supports multiple ways of using ByRef parameters.  I did a detailed explanation of the types in a recent blog entry

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2010/01/21/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx

What's happening here is that `Me` is not an assignable value.  So instead of passing `Me` as a byRef parameter, the VB compiler will instead pass a temporary.  This is loosely known as "Copy Back ByRef".  It effectively generates the following code

```
Dim temp = Me
Initialize(temp, SomeParam)
```

There is no way to work around this in the case of `Me` because it's not assignable.  In the case of the local variable `foo` though this works as expected because `foo` is a valid ByRef value.

Comment: WOW...that edge case took about 30 minutes of my life.  Thanks for the detailed explaination.